# Associate ID with input elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was wondering what would be the best way or approach to accomplish this. I have a table row with two columns as inputs. I need to associate an ID to the input elements so that when the form is submitted I can identify which row the input belongs to. This is what I have.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="252748"> Tue - Mar 3rd 3:03 PM</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="notes[]">
            <option value="Parent Cancel" selected="">Parent Cancel</option>
            <option value="COVID-19">COVID-19</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="tel" name="hours[]" value="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="253081"> Wed - Mar 4th 2:03 PM</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="notes[]">
            <option value="Parent Cancel" selected="">Parent Cancel</option>
            <option value="COVID-19">COVID-19</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="tel" name="hours[]" value="0" readonly=""></td>
</tr>
```

[image: Table]

If I do this and submit the form this is what I will get 3 arrays: one for id, notes, and hours. How can I associate the ID to the correspondent notes and hours. Or is there a better way to do this?

thank you so much!

[image]

EDIT ***

```
$count = $_POST['rows'];

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{

    echo 'id ' . $_POST['id'][$i] . ' Notes ' . $_POST['notes'][$i] . ' Hours ' . $_POST['hours'][$i] . '<br>';

}
```

Comment: How are you building this html? If it's manually, just manually define different names. If it's dynamically, there must be a unique variable you can append to the name.

Comment: Please post your debug output (array) as a text instead of an image

Comment: Notice that the index in each of the arrays match. `id[0]` corresponds to `notes[0]` and `hours[0]`.

Comment: it is dynamic with php. @Dave yes! it is safe to assume the order of the array? I will not get ids mixed? like an id mixed with another one?

Comment: As the answer below says, as long as you continue with what you have you should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the indexes of each "row" match, you can loop over them and combine them into a new array which is more coherent, like this:

```php
$arr = [
    'id' => [
        0 => 123,
        1 => 456,
        2 => 789,
    ],
    'notes' => [
        0 => 'Parent Cancel',
        1 => 'COVID-19',
        2 => 'Parent Cancel',
    ],
    'hours' => [
        0 => 0,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 0,
    ],
];

$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr['id'] as $index => $id) {
    $newArr[$id] = [
            'notes' => $arr['notes'][$index],
            'hours' => $arr['hours'][$index],
    ];
}

var_export($newArr);
```

output:

```php
array (
  123 =>
  array (
    'notes' => 'Parent Cancel',
    'hours' => 0,
  ),
  456 =>
  array (
    'notes' => 'COVID-19',
    'hours' => 1,
  ),
  789 =>
  array (
    'notes' => 'Parent Cancel',
    'hours' => 0,
  ),
)
```

Note however that this only works as long as all indices are always around, (no gaps) - which should be the case with your current HTML.

An alternative approach would be to put the ID (integer) as the index in the input fields, however this would still leave you with two arrays that you still have to combine (one for the notes and one for the hours). So it would not exactly make it any easier imho.

Comment: Thank you! I could also loop through all records and each loop will be a row with the correspondent ID $id = $_POST['id'][$i];             $notes = $_POST['notes'][$i];             $hours = $_POST['hours'][$i];

Comment: Yes, you sure could! It is appreciated if you accept and/or upvote the answer that solved your problem ;)

Comment: Thank you! I just did. Also, do you know how would I go about preventing the user to submit the form if hours is 0 where COVID-19 is selected. I need to associate the notes with the correspondent hours but in jquery to prevent form submission

Comment: Maybe, but seeing as this is a completely different question you should just ask an entirely new one. People will certainly be able to help.